# Service utilization time and Bar chart

Tags: anylogic

In my model I want to calculate the utilized time in seconds in service block and display it in bar chart in the form of percentage i.e. the percentage of service time of service block 1 out of the total time of the model.

For example:

```
service block 1= 60 second 
service block 2= 10 second 
service block 3= 400 second 

Total time of the service blocks = 410 seconds 

Service block 1 utilized time is   (60/470)*100= 12.7%
```

So I have calculated the utilized time as shown in [image: Picture 1]. The TimeIn is a variable in agent.

Picture 2 [image: Picture 2] shows the variable, Statistics and data set used for calculation and Bar chart display. D2 is the data set used in value chart display.

```
D2.add((agent.TimeIn-agent.TimeOut)/X)
```

My Question:

How can I get the bar chart to only display 12.7 percent out of the 100%. Currently it does show 100% every time I run the model.
[image: Picture 3]

I have used the following in the bar chart value window:

D2.getYMean()

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: sorry, not clear. Can you edit the question and do some example calcs with your numbers, i.e. what is AnyLogic doing and what you want to achieve instead? thx

Answer (score 0):

One of the straight forward way to measure time utilization in a service station is to use time measure as shown on the figure below
[image]

there is other ways in finding the utilization time for service station. one of the method mentioned by Anylogic help is `double utilization()` (Returns the mean utilization of this block. The returned value is the average (collected over time) of number of agents being serviced). I have tried using the `double utilization()`with service station but didn't work. However it dose work with delay (`x.stats.Utilization.mean()`[https://paginas.fe.up.pt/~ee01260/AnyLogic%20Models/Bank/AnyLogic_6_Enterprise_Library_Tutorial.pdf](https://paginas.fe.up.pt/%7Eee01260/AnyLogic%20Models/Bank/AnyLogic_6_Enterprise_Library_Tutorial.pdf)).